# What are the red berry-like structures at the base of my gardenia's flowers?

Tags: identification, gardenias

My [gardenia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gardenia) has a multitude of red, berry-like structures at what would have been the base of the flower. Given it is now November in South Carolina, what are they and will they produce a new plant?

Comment: would it be possible to post a photo?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your gardenia has fruited. Those are fruits. It is possible to raise them from seed, but it is time consuming and the results are often uneven in growth. Propagation from cuttings is normally a better idea.